# Problems with subcategories

Tags: category-theory

I've been told that the category of groups isn't a subcategory of **Set**. How come?

Wikipedia:

> Let **C** be a category. A subcategory **S** of **C** is given by
>
> a subcollection of objects of **C**, denoted ob(**S**),   a
>   subcollection of morphisms of **C**, denoted hom(**S**), such that:
>
> - for every $X$ in ob(**S**), the identity morphism $id_X\in$ hom(**S**)
> - for every morphism $f : X \to Y$ in hom(**S**), both the source $X$ and the    target $Y$ are in ob(**S**) for every pair of morphisms
>     $f,g\in$ hom(**S**)    $fg\in$ hom(**S**) whenever it is defined

Perhaps it's inadequate to consider ob(**Grp**) as a subcollection of ob(**Set**)?

---

In a comment Tobias Kildetoft indicated a condition about non uniqueness: *any given set can have more than one group structure*, but that condition does not appear to be included in the definition above.

My conclusion from the answer and the comments is that **Grp** formally is a subcategory of **Set** but that category theorist don't want to consider it as a subcategory because that is afflicted with a bad intuition.

---

OK, I realize that **Grp** isn't a subcategory of **Set** in the way I thought. The classical picture of a group as a set is not adequate enough for category theory. The equivalent category of set compositions, however, is a subcategory of **Set**.

Comment: The problem is that any given set can have more than one group structure.

Comment: From the set-theoretical point of view, group _is_ a set, i.e. $\text{Obj}(\mathbf{Grp})\subset\text{Obj}(\mathbf{Set})$ (I have in mind the following definition: group is a pair (two-elemented set) $(G,\bullet)$ etc). But it is not sufficient to say that $\mathbf{Grp}$ is a subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft. Yes, but that condition does not appear to be included in the definition?

Comment: So my previous comment gives a trivial proof that $\mathbf{Grp}$ _is not_ a subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$. If you want to prove that $\mathbf{Grp}$ is not _isomorphic_ or is not _equivalent_ to any subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$, you need another proof.

Comment: @Oskar the objects of the category of groups is not a subclass of the objects of the category of sets (it would be something like a multiclass or whatever)

Comment: I am not sure which condition you mean Lehs.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I am not sure about classes, because I only work with Grothendieck universes. By the definition above, every $\mathcal{U}$-small group is a $\mathcal{U}$-small set.

Comment: @Oskar Yes, but several different groups become the same set, so the groups do not form a subset of the sets.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft No, different groups are different sets by the abovementioned definition.

Comment: @Oskar Ahh, good point.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I have edited the question.

Comment: To give an example of what I mean, consider the set $\{1,2\}$. There are two ways to make this a group (they just happen to be isomorphic). Which of these would be the one you choose when making groups a subcategory of sets? But then what about the other one? Where did that go?

Comment: The comment by @Oskar, that a group is a set, is correct if one adopts one of the standard set-theoretic encodings, for example that a group is an ordered pair $(G,*)$ of a set and a binary operation and that an ordered pair $(x,y)$ is a set $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$. But then a homomorphism of groups is not a set-theoretic function between them. On the other hand, if you think of groups as sets by identifying a group with its underlying set (without $*$), then a group is *not* a set, since many groups would "be" the same set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definition of subcategory is very poorly behaved; in particular, it's not invariant under equivalence of categories. That is, it's possible to have three categories $S, C, D$ such that

1. $C$ is equivalent to $D$,
2. $S$ is equivalent to a subcategory of $C$, but
3. $S$ is not equivalent to a subcategory of $D$ (exercise).

The well-behaved notion of subcategory is that of [full subcategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/full+subcategory), for which the above doesn't happen. It's straightforward to prove that $\text{Grp}$ is not equivalent to a full subcategory of $\text{Set}$ (also exercise).

There is a natural forgetful functor $\text{Grp} \to \text{Set}$, but it is not full.

It is possible to exhibit a category equivalent to $\text{Set}$ in which $\text{Grp}$ is a (non-full) subcategory. Namely, take the category whose objects are groups but whose morphisms are arbitrary functions on underlying sets, not respecting the group structure. This category is equivalent to $\text{Set}$ (exercise; you need to know that every set admits at least one group structure). It has a subcategory with the same objects but whose morphisms do respect the group structure, which is of course just $\text{Grp}$. But no category theorist would describe this situation as "$\text{Grp}$ is a subcategory of $\text{Set}$."

Comment: It shouldn't be a disadvantage being Asperger when reading mathematical definitions, but the real world is far more complicated than the formal.

Comment: If we define a subcategory as a subobject in the 2-category of categories, what we call a “subcategory” will depend on the kind of “monomorphisms” we use to define subobjects.  With fully faithful morphisms, we get full subcategories.  With faithful morphisms, we get what I would consider as the most basic notion of subcategory, which coincide with concrete categories in the case of subcategories of $\mathsf{Set}$, so that $\mathsf{Grp}$ *is* a subcategory of $\mathsf{Set}$.  (And we can show that any faithful subcategory of $C$ is a “strict” subcategory of a category equivalent to $C$.)

Comment: @VejKse The problem is that way you'll also get many things people probably don't want to be subcategories, eg. $ω → 1$, and Grp $→$ Set for that matter. [Pseudomonic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudomonic+functor) functors seem like a potentially good compromise.

Comment: @Vej: I'm not aware of any author who thinks of faithful functors as defining a reasonable notion of subobject for categories. There is a general notion of monomorphism in higher category theory, and specialized to the 2-category of categories I believe it reproduces fully faithful functors.

Comment: So you wouldn't consider “sets with injective maps” as a subcategory of “sets with maps”? That the notion of full subcategory is better behaved than the concept of subcategory should not be of a concern here.

Comment: @egreg: yes, that's right. Whenever I say "subcategory" I mean full subcategory by default.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Well, that's not what's done in general.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you take this definition as given, the category of groups is not a subcategory of the category of sets.  It's true that if you define "a group" to be an ordered pair consisting of a set and a group structure, and if you define ordered pairs using Kuratowski's trick, then groups "are" sets.  However, the set of group homomorphisms between two groups is not a subset of the set of functions between those groups-as-ordered-pairs-as-sets.  In particular, Kuratowski ordered pair is always a set with either 1 or 2 elements, so there can be at most 4 functions from one of them to another one; but there are of course many pairs of groups between which there are more than 4 group homomorphisms.

Comment: OK, I can see the point, but that doesn't prohibit **Grp** from being a subcategory of **Set**. You could define a group to be a relation $R$ (the compostion) and a morphism to be certain functions between those relations. What we call a group homomorphism can be revealed from that morphism. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/231289/a-morphism-revealing-category

Comment: The disagreement seems to originate from a less adequate classical definition of a group and the more consistent viewpoint of the category terrorists. And I like disputes.

Comment: If you like disputes, maybe you would be better off reading philosophy.  Mathematicians generally like to *resolve* disputes.  (-:  Defining a group to be a relation is a clever trick, but that isn't the standard definition of "group".  So you haven't shown that Grp "is" a subcategory of Set, but rather that you can cook up a subcategory of Set that is equivalent (perhaps even isomorphic) to Grp, analogously to Qiaochu's example of how you can cook up a category equivalent to Set that contains Grp as a subcategory.

Comment: Yeah! But also I like to resolve the disputes. Thanks for helping me understand!